# Changing the font color of menu navbar

Tags: html, css

I tried to change some color of text in bootstrap, I'm new with that.

I need to change the text color in menu to white.
On mouse hover it should change to black text and white background.

```css
.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #222;
  padding: 2px 1px;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ff3546;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.carousel-control {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: -35px;

}
.left.carousel-control {
  right: 30px;
  left: inherit;
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, 
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

#navbar-inverse {
 background: #c42027; 
 border: 0px;
}

#dropdown_toggle  {
  font-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-header">
 <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo/conlins logo.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse" id="collapse-navbar-collapse" >
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown_toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Product <span class="caret"></span></a>    
   <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
    <li class="col-sm-3">
     <ul>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Features</li>
      <li><a href="#">Auto Carousel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Carousel Control</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Left & Right Navigation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four Columns Grid</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Fonts</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Glyphicon</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Google Fonts</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="col-sm-3">
     <ul>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Plus</li>
      <li><a href="#">Navbar Inverse</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a></li>                            
      <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a></li>       
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="col-sm-3">
     <ul>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Much more</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Easy to Customize</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Custom Fonts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Slide down on Hover</a></li>                         
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>    
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Events <span class="caret"></span></a>    
   <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
    <li class="col-sm-3">
     <ul>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Features</li>
      <li><a href="#">Auto Carousel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Carousel Control</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Left & Right Navigation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four Columns Grid</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Fonts</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Glyphicon</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Google Fonts</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="col-sm-3">
     <ul>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Plus</li>
      <li><a href="#">Navbar Inverse</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pull Right Elements</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Coloured Headers</a></li>                            
      <li><a href="#">Primary Buttons & Default</a></li>       
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="col-sm-3">
     <ul>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Much more</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Easy to Customize</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Calls to action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Custom Fonts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Slide down on Hover</a></li>                         
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>    
  </li>
        <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
 </ul>
</div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: i edit the html please check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep or remove borders according to what you want

Add this to your css:

```
 .navbar-collapse{
  background-color:#ed1c24;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a{
  color:white;
  background-color:#ed1c24;
  margin:0;
  padding:0 15px;
  line-height:50px;
  display:block;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover{
  color:black;
  background-color:white;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover{
  color:black;
  background-color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to overrite bootstrap color style of anchor element and set !important like below,

```
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  color: #222 !important;
}
```

Comment: it dissapears all the li text from the dropdown menu

Comment: so you set to background-color to li also  .mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  background-color: black !important;
}

Comment: .mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a {
        background-color: white !important;
        color: black !important;
    }

        .mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
        .mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
            background-color: black !important;
            color: white !important;
        }

Comment: nothings happen sir, it change the font color only but if i hovers it the background is color black again and the menu font is also the same

Comment: i can send to you my codes, can you give your email to me

Comment: winodbhadaliya@gmail.com

Comment: just refer if html like below  
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a> menu1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>menu2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a> menu3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    
    so style is like,...

    ul > li > a {
        background-color: white !important;
        color: black !important;
    }

        ul > li > a:hover {
            background-color: black !important;
            color: white !important;
        }